# How to create Multi User Account

Tags: django, project

Please am really need you guys help on how to use Django to create Multi-user Account.
e.g Student, Lecturers, and Department login page(Admin).
in this system, the department will be the **Admin** to register the lecturers in order to have access and why the Student register on their own.

Am design a project titled **Online Assignment Submission System**
(it is my final year Project). I really need you guys help on how to go about it using Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options to deal with the user model in `Django`:

1. You could subclass `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` and add a choice field if the user is a student, teacher, etc.
2. Linking back from a related 'Profile' model. This comes in handy if you want different types of users to have different fields.

`models.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
    has_returned_books = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    hours_per_week = models.IntegerField()

# ... other profiles for department, etc.
```

Using this approach, you can query fields with the `ORM`: 
`user.teacherprofile.salary` or `user.studentprofile.subjects`.

When you have implemented your models you should read about the [permission system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) in `Django`. You can [limit access to logged-in users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) with help of a decorator or mixin.

Do some more research and come back asking specific question with examples of your recent work. The more work you put into the question, the more people will help you. Good luck!

Comment: i will like to ask. How can override Django username to use RegexField as my Login field.